# [Android]: Firebase database causes SQLiteDatabaseLockedException

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We used Firebase Database to synchronize data and we found an exception in crash report. Here is brief log:

```
Caused by com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
Failed to gain exclusive lock to Firebase Database's offline persistence. 
...
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): ,
while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
```

More detail log is [here](https://gist.github.com/CoderInOne/118377636f7fd9fa1b1d2a01d5849ba3). Here is our Firebase Database init code

```
// run in Application onCreate method
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Mostly, HTC mobiles with API level 19 are impact. We try to reproduce this
bug, but fail.

Comment: There is an active transaction (from some other code using the same connection, or from some other connection).

Comment: Any update? i'm facing the same issue

Comment: do you use multi-process on your application? the exception most likely because of multi-process. check the reference [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/jni/android_database_SQLiteConnection.cpp;l=47?q=SQLiteDatabaseLockedException)

Comment: try to use [enableMultiInstanceInvalidation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#enableMultiInstanceInvalidation())